# Como evitar que un listView vuelva al comienzo al actualizar su adaptador?

Tags: android, mysql, listview

Mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo un ListView que se completa a partir de datos obtenidos en una consulta mysql por medio de volley. Esta tarea se realiza una vez por segundo por medio de un timerTask. El ListView vuelve al primer item una vez por segundo (cada vez que se carga el nuevo adaptador), imposibilitando trabajar con los úlitmos valores del ListView, cuando hay que hacer scroll. adjunto el código.

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler2.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String iip = "192.168.1.34";
                String param = comandaActiva.getIdComanda();
                String consulta = "http://" + iip + "/Antonia/consultaComanda.php?id=" + param;

                EnviarRecibirDatos(consulta);
            }
        });
    }
};
timer.schedule(task, 100, 1000);  //ejecutar en intervalo de 1 segundo.


private RequestQueue queue;
private JSONArray ja;
public void EnviarRecibirDatos(String URL){

    if (queue == null) {
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    }


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ja = new JSONArray();
            response = response.replace("][",",");
            if (response.length()>0){
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "response>0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    ja = new JSONArray(response);
                    if(ja.length()>0){

                    //Log.i("sizejson",""+ja.length());
                    CargarListView(ja);}
                    else
                        {



                        }

                } catch (JSONException e) {


                }

            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
}

private ArrayList<String> lista;
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador;
public void CargarListView(JSONArray ja){

    lista = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int h = 0 ; h<lista.size();h++)
    {
        lista.remove(h);
    }
    if(ja.length()>0){
    for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i+=4){

        try {
            String temporal=ja.getString(i+1);

            lista.add(ja.getString(i)+") "+ja.getString(i+2)+"X"+temporal+"\n"+ja.getString(i+3)+" ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            lista.clear();
            lista.add("");
        }

    }}
    else
        {
            for(int r=0; r<lista.size();r++){
                lista.remove(r);}
        }

    int scroll = lvProductos.getMaxScrollAmount();



    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista);

    lvProductos.setAdapter(adaptador);
}
```

Gracias de antemano. Saludos

Comment: entonces, cada segundo borras toda la lista y la vuelves a cargar? o quieres agregar mas datos a los que ya estas desplegando?

Comment: En realidad la borro, ya que la lista, representa una comanda. Y varía según la mesa en la que se esta operando.  No son iguales los productos de la mesa uno que de la mesa 2. Necesito que Android "recuerde" la posición del scroll del ListView antes de volver a cargar la lista. Ya que sino. Cada segundo el scroll vuelve al inicio y ni puedo ver los últimos items

Comment: Sugiero fuertemente no usar ListView y utilizar RecyclerView. Casi que diría que no se debería usar ListView.

Comment: Tendré en cuenta el consejo. Soy bastante nuevo en Android, hay muchas diferencias con respecto a java

Comment: La más dolorosa es no disponer de jtable

Answer (score 1):

Existen 2 opciones,

1) puedes obtener la posición actual de tu primer vista visible en el listado

```
int firstPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

y usar esta posición para mover tu listView a esa posición:

```
listView.setSelection(firstPosition);
```

2) puedes usar el método:

> [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) Notifica a los observadores adjuntos que
>   los datos subyacentes se han cambiado y que cualquier Vista que
>   refleje el conjunto de datos debe actualizarse

En el método `CargarListView()` estas cargando los "nuevos" datos al `Adapter`, por lo tanto usa posteriormente `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
public void CargarListView(JSONArray ja){    
  ...
  ...
  ...
    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista);

    lvProductos.setAdapter(adaptador);

    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: muy buena respuesta j

Comment: Exactamente la respuesta que buscaba. Muchas gracias!!!. Ya mismo pruebo las soluciones. Saludos!!!

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag gracias Bruno, espero le ayude a fabri, saludos.

Comment: Acabo de probar las soluciones. notifyDataSetChanged() no existe. Probablemente por la api minima que utilizo (4.0). La primer opción, int firstPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(), funciona bastante bien. Pero si los items del listView ocupan mas de 2 lineas no puedo ver el último. Hay alguna forma de guardar la posición del scroll en lugar del primer item visible?

Comment: aiaia! es del Adapter :| ya lo cambié en la respuesta:  adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged(); @fabri

Comment: jajja ahora lo pruebo. Gracias de nuevo!!!